# JSON data into a Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put JSON data into Bootstrap Modal.

Sample JSON:

```
(/list.php?action=cam_settings&id=1)
{
"id":"1",
"title":"TEST",
"enabled":"1",
"source":"rtsp://192.168.1.10/user=admin_password=tlJwpbo6_channel=1_stream=0.sdp?real_stream"
}

(/list.php?action=cam_settings&id=2)
{
"id":"2",
"title":"TEST 2",
"enabled":"1",
"source":"rtsp://192.168.1.123/user=admin_password=tlJwpbo6_channel=1_stream=0.sdp?real_stream"
}
```

Sample Modal:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a id="1_ajax" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cam_settings" class="btn btn-warning">ID 1</a>
<a id="2_ajax" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cam_settings" class="btn btn-warning">ID 2</a>

<!-- Camera Settings Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="cam_settings" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cam_settings">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="cam_settings">Настройки камеры</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
  <form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="id">ID</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="id" name="id" required class="form-control input-lg">
              </div>
            </div>
         
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="name">Название</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required class="form-control input-lg">
              </div>
            </div>
  
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="source">Источник</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="source" name="source" required class="form-control input-lg">
              </div>
            </div>
  
   <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Камера включена
    </label>
   </div>
  
   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Сохранить">
  </fieldset>
  </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Удалить камеру</button>   
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The question is how to transfer id (id="1_ajax") from buttons to GET query and how to parse the JSON answer? Do I need AngularJS?  Or it is possible to do with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a jQuery function to fill a modal for me, it works with all DOM element, not only modals.
You can see it in action here : https://jsfiddle.net/Loenix34/x9y30jnw/3/

Here is the code

```
if( $ ) {
    $.fn.fill = function(prefix, data) {
        $(this).each(function(key, value) {
            var container = $(this);
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                container.find("."+prefix+key).each(function() {
                    var element = $(this);
                    if( element.is("img") ) {
                        element.attr("src", value);
                    } else
                    if( element.is("a") ) {
                        element.attr("href", value);
                    } else
                    if( element.is(":input") ) {
                        element.val(value);
                    } else {
                        element.text(value);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    };
}
```

As you can see, it fills common elements with text, input as value, anchor as link and image as source.

Enjoy !

Comment: It's what I need. But what about transferring the ID?

Comment: What do you want to transfer the ID to ? If prefix is row_ and your property is id then i will look for .row_id to fill with the value of id.

Comment: The button has id="1_ajax". And I want to send id=1 in GET method